# EJB: seems I don't understand the crucial point

Tags: java, ejb, persistence, entity-bean

I'm new in EJB & persistence at all, so excuse me please if I'll ask a stupid question.
I read a book about EJB and JPA, and faces phrase that I don't understand at all:

> Intended to fully insulate developers from dealing directly with
>   persistence, it (EJB) introduced an interface-based approach, where
>   the concrete bean class was never directly used by client code.
>   Instead, a specialized bean compiler generated an implementation of
>   the bean interface to facilitate such things as persistence, security,
>   and transaction management, delegating the business logic to the
>   entity bean implementation.

and

> The notion of container-managed entity beans was introduced, where
>   bean classes became abstract and the server was responsible for
>   generating a subclass to manage the persistent data.

**What does it mean:**

1. Specialized bean compiler generated an implementation of the bean interface
2. server was responsible for  generating a subclass to manage the persistent data
   Actually I can't grasp what mean generate implementation/subclass, does it mean in runtime?

Thank you in advance.

**EDITED:**

> Finally, entity beans were modeled as remote objects that used RMI and
>   CORBA, introducing network overhead and restrictions that should never
>   have been added to a persistent object to begin with.

**Does it also sink into nothingness?**

Comment: Which version of EJB the book is talking about?

Comment: It talks about the evolution of EJB. The first phrase was about EJB1.0, the second - about EJB2.0. It is differ in EJB3.0?

Comment: Unless specificly needed for your workplace, forget about anything earlier than EJB 3. That was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Interfaces: To define a bean, you had to declare a `Local` interface and a `Remote` interface (if you were writting bean `MyEJB`, they had to be `MyEJBLocal` and `MyEJBRemote`; `MyEJB` would implement both). With that, the compiler generated some derived class implementing the methods, such methods would just connect to the EJB server to retrieve a bean and execute its methods.

I am not so sure about 2, since we had so many performance issues that we ended implementing JDBC logic in the Session beans (I know, I know)...

Comment: and one more question about RMI (see EDITED section of my question)

Comment: It just means that the `stub` classes generated by the compiler internally used `RMI` and `CORBA` to connect to the server. From the client POV, the entity or session bean was the remote object, accessible through the stubs.

Comment: Does it differ in nowadays? How?

Comment: It will be easier to say that what has not changed is the name, and that there are still Session (Stateless and Stateful) and Entity means, with the same meaning (but different implementation techniques).

Answer (score 1):

1. **Specialized Bean**: Since Java EE 5, EJB turn into annotation @EJB. All annotaion works like interface. This simple annotaion provide security, and transaction management, delegating the business logic at compile time.
2. **JPA**: No more entity bean remain since Java EE 5. Now if you put @Entity to on pojo than server will generate container-managed entity beans and communicate with database through persistance context.

Comment: Does it mean that 
'@EJB
MyBean'
is something like 
'MyBean implements EJBInterface'

Comment: and one more question about RMI (see EDITED section of my question)